# java string.split() issue

Tags: java, regex

While solving a [UVa question](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1135), I got this `String` and I need to split it an array of `String` removing `#` and `@`

`Brazil#2@1#Scotland`

I was getting a `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception when I used,

```
matchSummary.split("#@");
```

after researching solutions for this UVa question, I found that other experienced competitive programmers have done it like this,

```
string.split("[#@]");
```

and this passes the verdict of online judge.

I cant get this `String` split for this aforementioned `String`

My complete solution for this question is available here-  [see](http://codebloodedvalley.blogspot.in/2014/07/uva-10194-football-solution.html)

Can anybody explain to me why my code worked with `split("[#@]");`?

Comment: "*i need to split it an array of string removing `#` and `@`*" — How should the final array look like?

Comment: You tagged this question as regex - any decent regex tutorial should quickly tell you the difference between `"#@"` and `"[#@]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Java regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), characters enclosed in square brackets `[]` are called a character class.

This...

```
String input = "Brazil#2@1#Scotland";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("[#@]")));
```

... will split the `String` with either delimiter `#` or `@`, regardless of the order, and output:

```
[Brazil, 2, 1, Scotland]
```

It is equivalent in this case to:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("#|@")));
```

However, splitting with `#@` not enclosed by `[]` would search for a sequence of `#` followed by `@`.

This would not trigger any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` per se, it would just return a 1-sized `array` containing the original input `String`.

However, you're probably assuming the `array` size as `> 1` later in the code, hence the `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically using:
`split("#@");`

Will try to split only if it matches the characters `#` `@` concurrently

by using:

`split("[#@]");`

You are selecting from the class to either split on `#` or `@`

Answer (score 1):

`[#@]` means it will split on the `#` or the `@`.

For more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the split function is giving you an error is because @ and # are not together in the string, i would suggest using the StringTokenizer to split the string.

so create a new instance of it - StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer("Brazil#2@1#Scotland");

then set the delimeter to @ then split them, and then split them with the delimeter #